# Have no idea how to fix problems with even loop in telegram bot python

Tags: python, bots, python-asyncio, telegram

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, functions, sync, events
from Message import fetch_text, fetch_list
import time
from telethon.errors import *
from threading import *
import asyncio


class Shill():
    def __init__(self,T_id,T_hash,owner):
            self.t_id = T_id
            self.t_hash = T_hash
            self.owner = owner
            self.channel_list = fetch_list()
            self.message = fetch_text()

    def connection(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
```

I think, thast probles somwehere here, but cant define properly

```
        self.client = TelegramClient(self.owner, self.t_id, self.t_hash)
        self.client.start()
        print("Успешно залогинен")

    def join_channel(self):
        for var in self.channel_list:
            try:
                result = self.client(functions.channels.JoinChannelRequest(channel=var))
                print(f"{self.owner}. зашел в {var} ")
                time.sleep(1)

            except Exception as ex:
                print(ex)
                time.sleep(1)
                continue
        print("Вошли во все каналы")

    def send_message(self):
        while True:
            for var in self.channel_list:
                try:
                    entity = self.client.get_entity(var)
                    self.client.send_message(entity, self.message)
                    print(f"{self.owner}. отправлено")
                    print("________________________________________")
                    time.sleep(10)
                except Exception as ex:
                    print(ex)
                    time.sleep(600)
                    continue
            time.sleep(3600)

    def account(self):
        self.connection()
        self.join_channel()
        #self.send_message()


id0 = Shill("","","Me") # Telegram account info

t1 = Thread(target=id0.account)

t1.start()

t1.join()
```

Have no idea whats wrong with this asyncio and a tracebacks like \\Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-3' coro=<Connection._send_loop()
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-4' coro=<Connection._recv_loop()
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-5' coro=<MTProtoSender._send_loop()
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-6' coro=<MTProtoSender._recv_loop() running
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-7' coro=<UpdateMethods._update_loop()

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I was recently working with asyncio, and had similar problem. Mine showed up when I was KeyboardInterupting (ctrl+c) the script.

I see you are doing something with async functions, if you force close the asyncio loop, you might have tasks that are still waiting to run or finish running. That traceback is telling you that you have 5 tasks pending in the event loop. Do you in your Shill class call any async function?

When you want to stop the script you have to make sure the async functions finish and that event loop is stopped and closed.

Comment: I just call 'loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)' in Class Shill and later use Thread to make telegram session

Comment: May I ask why are you running it using Threads? Also the telethon library is designed to be used with asyncio. You can still use a custom class just use asyncio in it. https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/basic/quick-start.html

Comment: couse i want to use about 5 accounts to send messages into joined groups, but at first i want to check by using only 1 account
i will check, ty